# OpenMP provides 13.5 times improvement on Visual Studio 2010 but nothing on Unix

Tags: linux, openmp

I'm a new OpenMP user and have parallelized code that runs 13.5 times faster (14 threads) on Visual Studio 2010 (Windows 7 Ultimate x64).  The performance on CentOS 5.8 x64 (gcc 4.1.2) or SUSE x64 (gcc 4.5.1) is zip.  I've verified that multiple threads are being used.  Is there some system flag or option I need to turn on?  Yes, OMP_NUM_THREADS is in the environment and set to 8.  The CentOS machine is a dual xenon processor.

Comment: I've since discovered that the Windows 7 machine is using RevoDrive 3 with measured 1200 MB/sec performance.  The CentOS machine (using a SSD) drive is reporting only 26 MB/sec even though the SSD is supposed to be capable of 500 MB/sec.  At that performance level it was severly I/O bound and extra threads were useless.  Now trying to understand I/O performance on CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

With 8 cores, it sounds nearly impossible to have a 13.5 times speedup, whatever the number of threads you use.

I suspect your measurement is wrong. How do you measure performance ?
In Unix, the command "time ./myprogram" will return 3 different times. The "real" time is the time your are interested in, while the "user" time is the cpu time (sum of times spent on each core).
In windows I have no idea, but I guess you find a "user" time which is 13.5 times larger than the "cpu" time, which does not say anything about speedup, but rather that all your 14 threads are in use.

You should rather compare the "real" time between a single thread program and an openmp program.

Comment: I have hyper-threads turned on giving me 16 columns on the performance monitor.  I actually got the 13.5 x performance when using 16 threads.

Comment: ok, but we need more information. Can you please tell us what "time ./myprogram" tells you ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the correct compiler / linker switches, eg `-fopenmp -lgomp` ?  Maybe try a simple example from the OpenMP docs first to prove you have the setup right.

Comment: On the Linux machines I used -fopenmp (I didn't have to use -lgomp).  I have the simple "hello world" OpenMP example that I found on OpenMP.org built into my program which I call at the beginning to see 16 separate threads being called.

Comment: I think you do for the linking.